# What is the function "get_s()" in MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, c, mingw, mingw-w64

I found that MinGW-w64 compiler have a function `get_s()`,who can tell me the difference between `gets_s()` and `get_s()`，thanks!

Comment: This looks like a typo, where did you find a reference to a `get_s()` function?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets
The API is different between the two. I think `gets_s` is more prefered because it's safer, because with `gets_s` you have to provide it a `size` as the second parameter.

Comment: `gets_s` is Windows-specific and non-portable, while `fgets` is both portable _and_ has a `size` parameter. I don't know about `get_s`, though.

Comment: @chqrlie I want to use `gets_s` but I found myself typed `get_s`.It can also be  compiled successfully.then I found this in `stdio.h`:
```cpp
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl gets_s(char*,rsize_t);
  __DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_0(char*,get_s,char,_DstBuf)
```
but I can't understand this snippet

Comment: You don't have to understand much about that snippet. [`gets_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), is optional as of C11. and is pretty straight forward if the feature-macros are properly engaged. Give it a buffer and a size. Several specific conditions can lead to a *constraint handler* being fired, the default of which in the MS implementation case being a processor termination. Personally, I just use `fgets`, as it is guaranteed provided by compliant implementations, and I get to choose whether I want to terminate my own program.

Comment: @Erlkoenig No, `gets_s` is C standard since C11, but not recommended still.

Comment: And yeah it seems like a typo, can't reproduce. Just forget about anything named `get*` and use `fgets`.

Comment: @WhozCraig so what is the difference between `get_s()` and `gets_s()`

Comment: No clue. Never heard of the former. Consult the documentation of whatever library and/or toolkit you're getting it from, because it sure isn't part of the standard C library.